# Python: lxml formatting

Tags: python, lxml

I need to create an xml file. Is there a possibility to get the following formatting? The len of the list is normally bigger and always different. So I can not use if loop with a request of the list length.

Needed formatting:

```
<test>
  <fanart>
    <thumb preview="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/krkkgbtWHlMXVLbPGdIxzxKJERM.jpg">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/krkkgbtWHlMXVLbPGdIxzxKJERM.jpg</thumb>
    <thumb preview="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/izYCpovyAIKLI2i3gmhSKxlR8Pk.jpg">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/izYCpovyAIKLI2i3gmhSKxlR8Pk.jpg</thumb>
    <thumb preview="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/vmrnxaYx1xlG5jhuFUs51dd3VPA.jpg">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/vmrnxaYx1xlG5jhuFUs51dd3VPA.jpg</thumb>
    <thumb preview="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/pPFbXcONHBntJIAsEn8TaIPPCpZ.jpg">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/pPFbXcONHBntJIAsEn8TaIPPCpZ.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
</test>
```

Code:

```
import lxml.builder

E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
nfo = E.test()

list = [('http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/krkkgbtWHlMXVLbPGdIxzxKJERM.jpg','http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/krkkgbtWHlMXVLbPGdIxzxKJERM.jpg'),
        ('http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/izYCpovyAIKLI2i3gmhSKxlR8Pk.jpg','http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/izYCpovyAIKLI2i3gmhSKxlR8Pk.jpg'),
        ('http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/vmrnxaYx1xlG5jhuFUs51dd3VPA.jpg','http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/vmrnxaYx1xlG5jhuFUs51dd3VPA.jpg'),
        ('http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/pPFbXcONHBntJIAsEn8TaIPPCpZ.jpg','http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/pPFbXcONHBntJIAsEn8TaIPPCpZ.jpg')]

for (link_thumb, link_orig) in list:
    fanart = E.fanart(E.thumb(link_orig,preview=link_thumb))
    nfo.append(fanart)


print lxml.etree.tostring(nfo, pretty_print=True)
```

Output:

```
<test>
  <fanart>
    <thumb preview="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/krkkgbtWHlMXVLbPGdIxzxKJERM.jpg">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/krkkgbtWHlMXVLbPGdIxzxKJERM.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <thumb preview="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/izYCpovyAIKLI2i3gmhSKxlR8Pk.jpg">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/izYCpovyAIKLI2i3gmhSKxlR8Pk.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <thumb preview="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/vmrnxaYx1xlG5jhuFUs51dd3VPA.jpg">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/vmrnxaYx1xlG5jhuFUs51dd3VPA.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
  <fanart>
    <thumb preview="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/pPFbXcONHBntJIAsEn8TaIPPCpZ.jpg">http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/pPFbXcONHBntJIAsEn8TaIPPCpZ.jpg</thumb>
  </fanart>
</test>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appended `fanart` elements for each `image`; instead make 1 `fanart` element and append it to the `nfo`; then append each image into that `fanart` element:

```
import lxml.builder

E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
nfo = E.test()
fanart = E.fanart()
nfo.append(fanart)    

items = [('http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/krkkgbtWHlMXVLbPGdIxzxKJERM.jpg','http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/krkkgbtWHlMXVLbPGdIxzxKJERM.jpg'),
        ('http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/izYCpovyAIKLI2i3gmhSKxlR8Pk.jpg','http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/izYCpovyAIKLI2i3gmhSKxlR8Pk.jpg'),
        ('http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/vmrnxaYx1xlG5jhuFUs51dd3VPA.jpg','http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/vmrnxaYx1xlG5jhuFUs51dd3VPA.jpg'),
        ('http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/pPFbXcONHBntJIAsEn8TaIPPCpZ.jpg','http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/pPFbXcONHBntJIAsEn8TaIPPCpZ.jpg')]

for (link_thumb, link_orig) in items:
    fanart.append(E.thumb(link_orig,preview=link_thumb))    

print lxml.etree.tostring(nfo, pretty_print=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's so easy.

Comment: In case I solved your problem then you could also accept my answer ;)